# wcf endpoint relative address

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I'm just learning wcf and can't understand one very basic thing.

I'm creating a WCF service which I want to be hosted in IIS just like web application with it's own path like `http://myhost/myapp/` and everything.

I'm creating the WCF service project in VS, I've got an `*.svc` file describing it, then I define a simple endpoint to it like that:

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="wcf_service_auth.IPshService" />
```

Then I publish this service like an IIS web application to a virtual directory, let's assume it's name `psh_pub`, so I can access the service via url `http://localhost/psh_pub/pshservice.svc/`. It shows me WCF greetings page and gives me a link to WSDL, which gives me correct wsdl description.

That's ok.

The next step - I want to add a MEX endpoint. I add to config:

```
<endpoint address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

That's ok too, the endpoint is accessible at address `http://localhost/psh_pub/pshservice.svc/mex` and `WcfTestClient.exe` gives me correct config from that url.

Here the problem comes.

I have a WCF service working under IIS and I want to add one more endpoint to it. For example let it be a `net.tcp` endpoint. The IIS is configured by default to accept `net.tcp` connections at port 808 and I'm adding `net.tcp` protocol to properties of my web app, and I want to add an endpoint to my service like that:

```
<endpoint address=""
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          contract="wcf_service_auth.IPshService"  />
```

and now I assume that my service should be accessible via the url `net.tcp://localhost:808/psh_pub/pshservice.svc`. But it's not. And every "how-to" and manual on the web tells that I should specify full address in the config file like that:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:808/psh_pub/pshservice.svc" 
          binding="netTcpBinding" 
          contract="wcf_service_auth.IPshService" />
```

And if I do so, it works. But if host the service in another virtual directory, I'll need to change the config. If I host it on the other server, I'll need to change config. If I host it on multiple servers, I'll have to maintain as many configs as servers I have.

So the main questions is:

Is there any way in WCF to specify a `net.tcp` (or https) endpoint of a IIS-hosted WCF service without specifying absolute url for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to define a **base address** for your `net.tcp` service endpoints:

```
<service name="YourServiceName">
   <host>
       <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/psh_pub/" />
       </baseAddresses>
   </host>
```

Then you should be able to use relative addresses in your actual endpoints:

```
   <endpoint name="Tcp01"
             address="pshservice.svc" 
             binding="netTcpBinding" 
             contract="wcf_service_auth.IPshService" />
</service>
```

Comment: i don't know what i have just done, but i've got a working net.tcp endpoint with empty "address" parameter. anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

WCF file-less activation (.Net 4.0) will let you register under a relative virtual path using the relativeAddress attribute:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="relative-virtual-path/yourservice.svc"
           service="YourServiceImpl" />
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

> relative to the base address of the Web application

This link talks about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx

Comment: file-less activation lets me to get rid of .svc file, but i can't see how it can help to avoid specifying absolute host address for net.tcp endpoint. Do i miss something?

Comment: @pushist1y There is an attribute called relativeAddress under service activations which allows you to specify a relative virtual path for accessing your service. Does this not work for you?