# How to determine url of service endpoint address without .svc

Tags: web-services, wcf

I've inherited an application and was trying to figure out how the web service endpoints are configured. I've looked at links that discuss a base address and a file-less configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953057/wcf-endpoint-relative-address?rq=1) and this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) but I'm unclear if this is using a virtual directory on IIS or not. What is or where can I find the url to the service endpoints? There's no baseAddress or relativeAddress set up in my web.config. Here's what I have in the web.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="ecom.SomeServices.ServiceImplementation.SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="SomeService.SomeServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="/ShippingMethodMapping" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="LargeFileHttpBinding" contract="ecom.SomeServices.ServiceContracts.IShippingMethodMappingService" behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" bindingConfiguration="LargeFileHttpBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="/PaymentMethodMapping" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="LargeFileHttpBinding" contract="ecom.SomeServices.ServiceContracts.IPaymentMethodMappingService" behaviorConfiguration="LargeEndpointBehavior" bindingConfiguration="LargeFileHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Do I need to remote into the test IIS server and poke around?

Comment: The endpoint will be probably the dns configured in IIS (like http://yoursite.com) and the address of the service, "/ShippingMethodMapping" for example.

Comment: Okay, this helped. It ended up being just the single service on the web server, i.e., http:<server>/SomeServices/SomeService.svc. I didn't realize it but the above endpoint "addresses"/operations were all part of the original/base service contained within the <service> tag.